# Appinventor with Googlesheets

Tags: app-inventor

I have a spreadsheet and I need to do a search on it, scanning it and finding what I need. I have an input box that accepts anything, I just really need to find it in the spreadsheet. But I can't, can someone help me?
how to find values in spreadsheet using a input box?

I used condition to access what was researched in the spreadsheet, however, it was not a responsive code and I would have to test it cell by cell, which would not be worth it.

Comment: You may want to ask here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want to download all the spreadsheet data to your AppInventor app, and search there, or do you want to search the spreadsheet in-situ? What do you want do once you have a match? What if there is more than one match? You might want to ask this question on the AppInventor community https://community.appinventor.mit.edu.

Comment: I want to provide in the application only the data that I searched for. If have more than a information, I want to receive them all.

Comment: If your search values are in a specific column, and your spreadsheet is "anyone with the link", then you can use the Google Query Language (gviz) to return results: https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/use-gviz-to-get-and-query-google-sheet-data. If your search values could be in any column, then your will need to use textFinder:https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/10/17/taking-advantage-of-textfinder-for-google-spreadsheet/